# CakePHP: controller uses another model instead of its own

Tags: php, cakephp, model, controller

The situations looks like this: I have two models with controllers and everything, WrittenTest and WrittenTestAnswer. The problem is that whenever I try to access model WrittenTestAnswer, both from WrittenTestsController (using `$this->loadModel()` before) and from its own WrittenTestAnswersController, it somehow accesses WrittenTest instead. I noticed it when data wasn't saved to WrittenTestAnswer, `$this->WrittenTestAnswer->find()` also returned data from written_tests table. I have no idea what's going on. I checked names and stuff so many times already. I am using CakePHP 1.3. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
code from WrittenTestAnswer model:

```
class WrittenTestAnswer extends AppModel {

public $name = 'WrittenTestAnswer';
public $displayField = 'written_test_answer';
public $belongsTo = array(
      'WrittenTest' => array(
            'className' => 'WrittenTest', 
            'foreignKey' => 'written_test_id', 
      ), 
);

}
```

EDIT so for example this (in WrittenTestAnswersController)

```
debug($this->WrittenTestAnswer->name);
```

outputs `WrittenTest`. And

```
$this->WrittenTestAnswer->find('first');
```

returns first row from written_tests. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you paste the code from your `WrittenTestAnswer` model class?

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the model? If the relationships are setup correctly, you shouldn't need to use `$this->loadModel()` at all. You can just access the related model through its parent like so:

```
$this->WrittenTest->WrittenTestAnswer->find('all');
```

This might not be the cause of your problems but we cannot tell until you actually post the code that's not working.

Comment: I've stated that it doesn't work even when I'm accessing WrittenTestAnswer from WrittenTestAnswersController, so this doesn't matter. And it's a simple find that doesn't work - it returns data from WrittenTest.

Comment: You didn't state HOW you were doing it, post the code that isn't working!